# navsat_transform broadcasting strange map->utm tf

Tags: navigation, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization, tf-tree, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there !

I'm trying to fuse data from different sensors (IMU, GPS and a rotating lidar) into an extended Kalman filter provided by robot_localization in order to drive my rover using move_base. I'm running ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04.

With the right packages i was able to publish three topics for my three sensors :

- /gps/fix : sensor_msgs/NavSatFix
- /imu/data : sensor_msgs/Imu
- /pose_with_covariance_stamped :  geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped (let's call it /pose)

Here's how my navsat_transform_node and ekf_localization node are set :

**navsat_transform_node**

- Input : /imu/data, /gps/fix, /odometry/filtered
- Output : /odometry/gps

**ekf_gps**

- Input : /imu/data, /pose, /odometry/gps
- Output : /odometry/filtered

According to REP105 and what I've read in this forum I think my frames are set correctly, see the tf tree below:

image:[image] (in the link below if not working)

Now when i plot my topics in rviz i see **/odometry/filtered drifting to infinity and beyond** and i don't understand why ... Looking at my tf tree it looks like the map->utm transform is bugged, however i got this message in my navsat_transform terminal :

INFO[1470904382.578813798]: World frame->utm transform is Origin: (-4945736.2295890189707 677781.95941346196923 -470427.19763114472153)
Rotation (RPY): (0.085877088202917686854, -0.066475908266541719471, -1.5762575291089457874)

My initial pose doesn't look right, as for my orientation i've offseted my imu and my robot is almost pointing north so that looks correct.

I have rosbag all my topics and put my launch files link:[here]([https://www.dropbox.com/sh/obevfkity8y31tv/AADz-HDo7QbMdbeaX_7gOR6za?dl=0"debug](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/obevfkity8y31tv/AADz-HDo7QbMdbeaX_7gOR6za?dl=0%22debug) files dropbox") or link:[here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByDkLQ5Y0aXKd2hodU5acy1Bazg&usp=sharing) , i'd be glad if you could have a look at it and give me a clue of what i'm doing wrong ! I made the rosbag while the robot wasn't moving and pointing almost north.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1

Correcting the coma to a dot in *value="0,00436332"* (in navsat.launch) didn't change the drifting

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241551/navsat_transform-broadcasting-strange-map-%3Eutm-tf/) by [aymar111](https://answers.ros.org/users/27718/aymar111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just had a quick look through your navsat_transform_template.launch file. It looks like your magnetic declination parameter is set to

```
value="0,00436332"
```

With a comma "," instead of a dot "." I'm pretty sure this should be a dot. Otherwise, navsat_transform won't be using the correct magnetic declination, so its /odomtry/gps output will have a systematic error in it which will mess up everything from that point onwards. In general, double check your magnetic declination and yaw offset - I can't stress enough how critical those parameters are. If they aren't correct then navsat_transform will just give you erroneous data.

I'll have a look through the bag file when I can just to confirm if this is your problem.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aymar111](https://answers.ros.org/users/27718/aymar111/) on 2016-08-12**:
Thank you for noticing this mistake ! I'm adding an EDIT to my post, but whatsoever i ran with the "." instead of the "," and it didn't change the drifting ..